# showing submenu items using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a problem regarding showing/making visible submenu content by using various functions in jQuery. It wouldn't work, and I don't know why. I would appreciate if anyone could help me.

The basic idea is that as I hover on the link (it's an image in the real application) I need the submenu to pop up.

```
function openMenu() {
    $("#block a").hover(function () {
        $("#block .list .submenu").css({
            visibility: "visible"
        });

        $("#block .list .submenu").css({
            display: "block"
        });

        $("#block .list .submenu").show();
        $("#block .list .submenu").css({"color": "yellow"});
    });
}
```

[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/mbax9dac/mktv9/)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have a trigger outside of the list? Or why you are using jQuery to show/hide on :hover?

Comment: Yes, I did. But in real application I have it. Added it just know to fiddle

Comment: instead of trigger there is an image, and as I hover over image I want sub menu to pop up. I'm just experimenting with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cause you javascript never runs ,you write the code which you think that it will run in a function, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#block a").hover(function () {
        $("#block .list .submenu").css({
            visibility: "visible"
        });

        $("#block .list .submenu").css({
            display: "block"
        });

        $("#block .list .submenu").show();
        $("#block .list .submenu").css({"color": "yellow"});
    });
});
```

Comment: I have this code in the another file and it's linked to page. The thing is another code works fine, but this piece just wouldnt work. I thought I might have some syntax problem

Comment: i tested it on my computer,it works. in you code ,you neet to trigger openMenu() function then it should works also .you need to hide() the submenu before the page load.

Comment: well, openMenu() is triggered on the page load, as it should. but i dont understand why I need to hide menu, as it already hidden with css rule

Comment: i didn't see any code that use to hide menu; do you have fb or something , i can help you to figure out what is the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont. But css code is in my jsfiddle link above, you can check it if you want to. thanks!

Comment: p
{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
}

.list li
{
    list-style:none;
}

.list li .submenu
{

}

Comment: p
{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
}

.list li
{
    list-style:none;
}

.list li .submenu
{

}  /*this is you css. may i ask you which line hide the menu?*/

Comment: yse,why not.create one

Comment: ah, i dont have enough reputation. I will open FB then

Answer (score 0):

For menu's I recommend using the Superfish Menu plugin, developed by Joel Brich

GitHub repo: https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish

It's great because you can customize it as far as you wish, and you have great retro compatibility with all kind of mobile and desktop browsers.

Best,
Santiago